# How to feed variable-length of speech feature to RNN(LSTM) for Speech Recognition?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, speech-to-text

I am trying to build a Speech Recognition System, which is a squence-to-sequence model. But I got confused about how to feed the extracted feature(fbank with the dimension of 40) to LSTM. As far as I have found, there are different methods to feed the data as input into LSTM. However, I have a doubt to fully understand them. I would be so thankful if someone tells me whether or not I am correct in the following cases.

**Case 1:**
In the convenient format [*Batch_Size*, *Time_Step*, *Feature_Dim*], If I select [1, *None*, 40], the length of each sequence(utterance) can be varied? if so, in this case I do not need to pad each sequence, am I right?

**Case 2:** 
If all input sequences are padded to the same length, the Batch_Size can be any value like 64, 128 and etc?

Finally, one more question, do I notice that the Time_Step in each Batch should be the same?

I would be so thankful if someone can help me to get rid of my doubts or give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how your system built is it end-to-end training or did u use hand-engineering features such MFCC? one more note the main use of RNN's is to have a variable-length input.

Comment: Yes, it is an end-to-end ASR and we extracted fbank features(40 dims for each frame) instead of MFCC, but they mostly are the same. Do you mean I do not need to do padding?

Comment: you need to define a fixed size vector for all of the audio files (in that case you need to Apply padding before feeding the input )

Comment: for the second case, if you padded the input you can set the batch size to different values. if you found my answer helpful please mark it as a correct answer.